# How do I use a global lua_State * in a game engine?

Tags: c, optimization, lua, game-engine

In my engine, currently, every entity has its own [`lua_State *`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_State) linked to it. The base Entity class has a function `linkScript(const char *scriptPath)` that will call [`luaL_dofile(luaState, scriptPath)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_dofile). All of this works perfectly fine, but the game is still rather small. I've been reading around, and I noticed that what I'm doing is considered bad practise. It's recommended that I have a global `lua_State *` and load all of the functions into global memory. At first, I thought to myself "Okay, simple enough," but I soon ran into a problem: every Lua file defines their own `init()`, `tick()` and applies some EventHooks. How do I share a global `lua_State *` without each script overwriting the previous script's definition of these functions? These functions are called every frame and or every time an event is triggered. I need to be able to differentiate between each script's implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to treat each script as an object with its own functions. When you load the script and run it, you don't want its functions to go in global namespace, rather in table specific to it, and have a global table where all such tables are stored.

There are many ways of doing this, but one that comes to mind is this: you create a global table allObjects, then for each script you do:

```
-- object1Script.lua
allObjects.object1 = {
    init = function() 
        ...
        end, 
    tick = function()
        ...
        end
}
```

You do the above for each script, but each one creates a different entry in the `allObjects` table, `object1` for first script, `object2` for second script, etc. If you don't want to name the scripts you could use an array i.e. `allObjects.insert( { ... table of init, tick etc functions ...} )`. Presumably you would loop through allObjects table to call each "object"'s init() or tick() etc as appropriate.

I think the above is the basic approach, hopefully it inspires you to find your own.

Comment: Perfect, it was just what I needed. A very simple solution, I'm surprised I didn't even think of this.